# What is the best (less code) to use angularjs and twitter-bootstrap for forms backed in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I want to handle closer to 100% of my client side code with angularjs, I'm using twitter-bootstrap also, so the thing is twitter-bootstrap make me do so much html code to create forms, i like solutions like simple-form, but they consist in a model instance to do the form_for thing, and create an instance just for that doesn't sounds cool to me.

Does anyone knows any gem or something of those libraries that I'm missing?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a library full of directives for angularjs and bootstrap: http://angular-ui.github.io/

Comment: thanks, but i checked the http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ section, there is nothing about forms there, so far i understand it is just a implementation of the part of bootstrap that uses jquery in angular, i was looking for something like simple-form but in a way that theres no need to have an instanced model to build a form